# Does sending SingleEmailMessage with template use a SOQL query?

Tags: email, email-template, singleemailmessage

I'm getting a somewhat strange error message when trying to send a list of emails

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 11;
>   first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, System.LimitException: Too many SOQL
>   queries: 101:

The code basically just creates a list of SingleEmailMessages from different objects and sends them together.  The error message points to the `Messaging.sendEmail()` function.

Example Code:

```
for(My_Object__c obj : objectsForEmail){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(senderId);
        msg.setTemplateId(templateId);
        msg.setWhatId(obj.Id);
        msg.setTargetObjectId(obj.Contact__c);
        messages.add(msg);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

### Update

I wrote a simple tests to try to get to the bottom of this:

```
@isTest
private static void testEmail(){
    Contact c = TestUtil.generateContact();
    c.email = TestUtil.generateRandomEmail();
    insert c;

    Test.startTest();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage templateEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    templateEmail.setTemplateId('00X18000000M3XD');
    templateEmail.setTargetObjectId(c.id);
    System.debug('send email XX');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{templateEmail});
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

[image: Debug Log]

It appears somehow sending an email is somehow causing a managed package "Mass Edit Activities" to execute which in turn is causing a Task Trigger to run.

The package only runs if I send an email (*tested by commenting out the email code*) and after it runs, **my SOQL usage jumps up from 1 query to 13**!!!  The trigger that it causes to run only executes 1 query, so there are 11 unaccounted for queries being caused by the managed package.  I was also under the assumption that managed packages execute under a separate context of limits...

Comment: Are you sure the exception is due to the above code? It seems somehow there is more than 100 SOQL queries running in a single instance.

Comment: @SarojBera the exception points to the line Messaging.sendEmail(messages);  this is running inside of a trigger thought and the exception order is very complicated (multiple other triggers and worksflow triggering other triggers)

Comment: What type of template is set in 'templateid'. Is is Visual force template having controller.

Comment: @curious_techy it's a regular html/plain text template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sendEmail doesn't take a SOQL query, although it does consume a DML statement.

Looking at your stack trace the extra queries are coming from the task trigger. You can use the `Email.setSaveAsActivity(false);` to avoid creating the Task.